# Webscrape Python output doesn't match website

Tags: python, web-scraping

## EDITED

I am scraping a website and am trying to get the amount of search results from my search so that I can use that number to determine how many pages to scrape. Here is an example

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

url_list = []
item_list = []
page_ctr = 0
item_ctr = 0

num_pages = 0;
my_url = 'https://www.walmart.com/search/?query=games&20lego'
get_page_num = requests.get(my_url)
num = get_page_num.content
num_soup = BeautifulSoup(num, 'lxml')
num_soup.prettify()
print(num_soup.prettify())
#num_sum = num_soup.find('div', {'class': 'result-summary-container'}).text()
#print(num_sum)
#num_pages = (num_sum[1]/40) + 1
```

When I inspect the element in chrome and just looking at the page with my eyes, I see 230 results, but when I look at my output i get something more like this:

```
</span> of 1,000+ results</div>
```

very new to web scraping, can anyone explain this?

Comment: put real url so we could see this problem.

Comment: it can have different problems: ie. pages may uses JavaScript but `Beatufulsoup`/`requests` can't run `JavaScript. Web page may can check header `User-Agent` to send different results for different devices and program. It can check other properties from real browser to send different content. Better show real URL so we could see problem.

Comment: was not sure of the policy.

Comment: post has been edited

Comment: when I run normally in browser and scroll to the end then I see links to next pages but when I turn off JavaScript and load page then I see only 10 objects on page and there is no links to next pages. You may have to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real browser and get links to next pages - and then you don't have to calculate how many pages you have to scrape.

Comment: 1000+ can means 1500, 2000, 10 000, etc. So you can't know if it will be 25 or more pages. You can get next pages untill you get status code different then `200`. Check `get_page_num.status_code`

Comment: ok this is good info and when you say turn javascript off, what exactly does that mean?

Comment: open web browser, find  in web browser option which turns off JavaScript (or use some extension to turn it off) and then visit page in web browser. it will load page without running JavaScript code - and you will see what `BeautifulSoup` can get from server.

Comment: BTW: [extension to turn on/off JavaScript](https://add0n.com/javascript-toggler.html) which I use in Firefox

Comment: @furas I edited my post to show the url, could you please be decent and remove the downvote from my post so I can actually make posts again and get help with my schoolwork during this pandemic, thank you.